# No results output on union search query when trying to link it to source via id

Tags: php, mysqli, union

I have 4 tables in my db. I'm using union to search through all tables to output results. It works as expected however when i try to identify the source to add an href link to its desired output page i get no results. My code below is as follows

I have tried adding a literal string. Ive tried adding an alias without any luck.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include'db.php';
if(!empty($_POST))
{
      $aKeyword = explode(" ", $_POST['keyword']);
      $query ="SELECT *,'articles' as source FROM tbl_articles WHERE name like '%" . $aKeyword[0] . "%'
      UNION 
      SELECT  *, 'tbl_album' as source FROM tbl_album WHERE name like '%" . $aKeyword[0] . "%'
      UNION 
      SELECT  *, 'tbl_gallery' as source FROM tbl_gallery WHERE gname like '%" . $aKeyword[0] . "%'
      UNION 
      SELECT  *, 'tbl_events' as source FROM tbl_events WHERE name like '%" . $aKeyword[0] . "%'";

     for($i = 1; $i < count($aKeyword); $i++) {
        if(!empty($aKeyword[$i])) {
            $query .= " OR name like '%" . $aKeyword[$i] . "%'";
        }
      }

     $result = $db->query($query);
     echo "<br>You have searched for keywords: " . $_POST['keyword'];

     if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row_count=0;
        echo "<br>Result Found: ";

        While($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
            $row_count++;
            if($row == 'source') 
            echo "<p><a href='result1.php?artid=".$row["artid"]."'>".$row["name"]."</a></p>";
            } 
            else if($row == 'source') 
            {
            echo "<p><a href='result2.php?id=".$row["albumid"]."'>".$row["name"]."</a></p>";
            }
            else if($row =='source')
            {
            echo "<p><a href='result3.php?gid=".$row["gid"]."'>".$row["gname"]."</a></p>";
            }  

        }

    }
    else {
        echo "<br>Result Found: NONE";
    }
}

?>
```

i need to pass the correct ids to their respective result pages e.g tbl_articles to results1.php and tbl_album to results2.php and tbl_events to results3.php etc. Currently when running the query i get no results.

Comment: `$row` will be an array containing the row data, not a string, so I'm unsure what `$row == 'source` is supposed to be doing. Should those `if`s be more like `if ($row['source'] === 'tbl_events')`?

Comment: thats the part ive been stuck on. How to identify the table and pass the id as an href link. I will give your suggestion a go

Comment: Im getting results now however im getting the following error Notice: Undefined index: id

Comment: Your code doesn't show the use of an index `id`, so probably elsewhere, or maybe you've a typo?

Comment: Thanks @Jonnix for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Because the union operator combines the result set i could not use the other column id names. I needed to use the first query id name and everything is now working as expected.